# When using "Github Flow", what if my next feature depends on code from a pending Pull Request?

Tags: git, branching

We are experimenting with "Github Flow", as defined [here](http://scottchacon.com/2011/08/31/github-flow.html).

In short, every change starts off as a well-named branch off of master. When it's done, you open a PR for that branch, it gets reviewed, and then gets merged into master. It's a very simple workflow.

However, we have run into this a couple of times: I develop feature X, and open a PR for it. While I'm waiting for the PR for X to be reviewed, I want to start work on another feature Y, but I need the code from PR X.  Should I just start a branch from the feature X branch, or if I've already started feature Y, just merge feature X into the feature Y branch? It seems so, but I wanted to check with other teams that are following this model to see how they handled multiple PRs and features that are dependent upon each other.

Answer (score 4):

I start the new work based off branch `X`. As branch `X` changes from code reviews, continue to merge it into your new branch `Y`